# Alignment and height of child DIVs

Tags: html, css

**Hy there,**

I'm experiencing some (understanding) problems with some HTML & CSS of mine.

I have multiple DIVs (.item) inside a parent DIV (.group). The height of those child DIVs depends on their content which is dynamic.

*Working example with static content:* http://jsfiddle.net/YfDWL/

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">item 1</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">item 2</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag1</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag2</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag3</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">item 3</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag1</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">item 1</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag1</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag2</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag3</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">item 2</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag1</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-title">item 3</div>
        <div class="item-tag">tag1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.group {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that all item DIVs inside a group should have the same height and should be aligned at the top. This brings me to a few problems:

1. **The alignment**
   How can i align all item DIVs at the top of the group? Right now they are aligned at the bottom as you can see at the example...
2. **The height**
   As I've seen in other questions it seems that this can't be done with pure HTML/CSS. Therefore I've decided to use a little JS with JQuery to correct the height of the elements.
   *Working example:* http://jsfiddle.net/YfDWL/1/

JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    "use strict";

    var maxHeight;

    // Iterate through every group
    $('.group').each(function(idx, group) {
        maxHeight = 0;

        // Iterate through every item of the group and save the max height
        $(group).find('.item').each(function(idx, item) {
            var height = $(item).height();

            if (!maxHeight || (height > maxHeight)) {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
        });

        // Set the max height to all items inside the group
        if (maxHeight) {
            $(group).find('.item').css('height', maxHeight);
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, this is working ok, but the alignment still is a problem...

What I'd like to know now is where the alignment of the items comes from and how i could manage to put all items at the top of the group?

Additionally I'd love to here suggestions if the "same height"-problem could be solved more elegently and maybe without JS at all...

Thanks & best regards,
mik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top`

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align:top
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YfDWL/5/)**

---

You can refer this [***example***](http://jsfiddle.net/eVt2C/) to know how to get equal height without using js .

**[DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/arere4/1/edit)**

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 1):

**Add** `vertical-align:top;` on your `.item` class

```
.item{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/YfDWL/2/)***

***[Demo two](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/YfDWL/4/)***